# “You are not authorized to perform this action” with Low Search

Tags: low-search, error

I'm using Low Search on a site and during testing we are seeing the error “You are not authorized to perform this action” pretty frequently on the site after submitting the search form. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "You are not authorized to perform this action" error in this case was caused by users using their browser's back button while testing the form.

Adding the `secure="no"` parameter to the `exp:low_search:form` tag fixed the problem:

```
{exp:low_search:form secure="no"}
```

Comment: Correct. Note that the error is triggered because of the Secure Forms setting in EE: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/security/spam_protection.html#secure-form-mode and is true for any form generated by EE where you submit it, hit the back button, and submit it again.

Comment: I've locked this answer to see if it will stop the spam edits that keep getting posted.